# How to search for customer internal id using customer name? Suitescript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

As titled, how to search Netsuite internal id by other fields (ex: customer name)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to fetch customer-internalid

```
var customerSearchResult = search.create({
    type: 'customer', 
    filters: [{ name: 'entityid', operator: 'is', values: CUSTOMER_NAME }]
}).run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1 });

var customerInternalId = customerSearchResult[0].id;
```

where, `entityid` is id of customer name field and *CUSTOMER_NAME* is customer name that you want to search

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution. From now I will just use this search method in case I don't have the internalid.